# AWS Kinesis Video Streams - Producer SDK Java - JNI Exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, stream, java-stream, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I want to stream from my webcam to Kinesis Video Streams.
I have been reading the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-javaapi.html) and following the AWS [tutorials](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java).
After starting the DemoAppMain with the command:

> java -classpath target/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java-1.11.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar "-Daws.accessKeyId=fake_accessKeyID -Daws.secretKey=fake_secretKey -Dkvs-stream=fake_streamName -Djava.library.path=src\main\resources\lib\windows\KinesisVideoProducerJNI.dll" com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp.DemoAppMain

I obtain the following exceptions:

```
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library .so.
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library .dylib.
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library .dll.
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.so.
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.dylib.
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Unsatisfied link error. Directly loading native library libKinesisVideoProducerJNI.dll.
ERROR / KinesisVideo: 2021-10-18T10:50Z T1: EXCEPTION: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unsatisfied link error. Loading native library KinesisVideoProducerJNI failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no KinesisVideoProducerJNI in java.library.path: ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.ProducerException: Failed loading native library StatusCode: 0xd
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp.DemoAppMain.main(DemoAppMain.java:60)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.ProducerException: Failed loading native library StatusCode: 0xd
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.initializeLibrary(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:1177)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.create(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:229)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createSync(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:247)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createSync(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:212)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.client.NativeKinesisVideoClient.initializeNewKinesisVideoProducer(NativeKinesisVideoClient.java:238)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.client.NativeKinesisVideoClient.initialize(NativeKinesisVideoClient.java:119)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.java.client.KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.java:113)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.java.client.KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.java:86)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp.DemoAppMain.main(DemoAppMain.java:42)
```

I did research on the internet but without success. That's the reason why I make this post.
If anyone knows how to solve the problem, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states:

```
no KinesisVideoProducerJNI in java.library.path
```

How did you add this lib into your class path exactly?

The documentation states the prerequisites to have this library:

```
Your NativeLibraryPath must contain your KinesisVideoProducerJNI file, available at https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp

. The file name extension for this file depends on your operating system:

    KinesisVideoProducerJNI.so for Linux

    KinesisVideoProducerJNI.dylib for macOS

    KinesisVideoProducerJNI.dll for Windows
```

---

If you look at the windows folder, this library exists there:

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java/tree/master/src/main/resources/lib/windows

Perhaps doing this would work:

```
-Djava.library.path=src/main/resources/lib/windows  <-- The Directory!
```

java -classpath target/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java-1.11.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Daws.accessKeyId=<ACCESS_KEY> -Daws.secretKey=<SECRET_KEY> -Dkvs-stream=<KINESIS_VIDEO_STREAM_NAME>  **-Djava.library.path=src/main/resources/lib/windows** com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp.DemoAppMain

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't realize that I only needed the folder path and not the file path