# Unable to install Amazon Kinesis Video Streams Producer SDK Java

Tags: java, windows, amazon-kinesis

I've followed this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-javaapi.html) but I'm not able to build this sdk, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 01:34:40.783 [main] ERROR com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.java.client.KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory - Unsatisfied link error.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Username\amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java\src\main\resources\lib\windows\KinesisVideoProducerJNI.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:287) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2427) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeLibraryLoader.loadNativeLibraryIndirect(NativeLibraryLoader.java:76) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeLibraryLoader.loadNativeLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:44) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.initializeLibrary(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:1175) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.create(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:228) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createSync(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:246) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createSync(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:211) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.client.NativeKinesisVideoClient.initializeNewKinesisVideoProducer(NativeKinesisVideoClient.java:239) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.client.NativeKinesisVideoClient.initialize(NativeKinesisVideoClient.java:119) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.java.client.KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.java:111) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.java.client.KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.java:84) [classes/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp.DemoAppMain.main(DemoAppMain.java:42) [classes/:?]
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.ProducerException: Failed loading native library StatusCode: 0xd
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp.DemoAppMain.main(DemoAppMain.java:59)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.ProducerException: Failed loading native library StatusCode: 0xd
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.initializeLibrary(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:1176)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.create(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:228)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createSync(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:246)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createSync(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:211)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.client.NativeKinesisVideoClient.initializeNewKinesisVideoProducer(NativeKinesisVideoClient.java:239)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.client.NativeKinesisVideoClient.initialize(NativeKinesisVideoClient.java:119)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.java.client.KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.java:111)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.java.client.KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(KinesisVideoJavaClientFactory.java:84)
    at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp.DemoAppMain.main(DemoAppMain.java:42)
```

VM arguments set by me:

```
-Daws.accessKeyId=fake_key -Daws.secretKey=fake_secret_key -Djava.library.path=src/main/resources/lib/windows
```

I dont understand where the problem could be..

Comment: The first line of your error literally says what the error is. The native part of the SDK (KinesisVideoProducerJNI.dll) requires some DLLs that are not present on your system. use dependencies.exe or dependency walker to see which ones.

Comment: See `ailed loading native library StatusCode: 0xd`. One of the DLL  can not be found at `src/main/resources/lib/windows`

Comment: BTW This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614197/aws-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java-jni-exception

Comment: @VictorGUbin In that questin, the guy didn't specify the correct path, and I can't figure out which DLLs are missing. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: Check your stack trace `KinesisVideoProducerJNI.dll`. If DLL it there check that this DLL have same architecture as your JVM, I.e. if you Java for Windows x64 -  KinesisVideoProducerJNI.dll must be x64 not x32, ARM or what ever else.